# PayPal IPN testing

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I'm trying to get this PayPal IPN tutorial to work:
http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/using-paypals-instant-payment-notification-with-php

I setup everthing and now I'm in the PayPal sandbox and sending with the "Instant Payment Notification (IPN) simulator" a message to my "ipn.php" and nothing happends. 
The databse is still empty and I don't get a notification email.

I'm totally stuck with this. What can I do to find the error?
Thanks
Michael

Answer (score 5):

Make sure your listener is on port 80. It is undocumented, but the paypal IPN simulator will fail to send to any other port.

Comment: It's quite unbelievable that this isn't documented on the page somewhere. Thanks for this :)

Comment: Thanks!!!!, curl from console was working. But they forget this "detail" on web page.

Answer (score 3):

The tutorial URL does not open for me, I get a "No input file specified.".

My first suggestion would be to open the PHP script that processes the PayPal IPN and write the following in the beginning:

```
file_put_contents('dump.txt', print_r($_POST, true));
```

Ensure you have write permissions in the directory that holds the script because "dump.txt" file will be created there. This way you can see what PayPal sends to you and give you a starting debugging point.

Also check your web server error log for PHP errors that might be happening to you. The tutorials are often written long time ago, on different systems, different PHP version, etc.

Edit: Also you probably already know this but the IPN processing script should be publicly accessible, not some localhost stuff.